# Creating questions using Apps Script bring different results

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

Help, i have the following code to generate questions in App Script displayed in Google Form:

```
function clearMultipleChoiceQuestions() {
  var form = FormApp.openById(destinationForms); // Get the active form
  var items = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE); // Get all multiple-choice items
  let sleepDurations = items.length*1000
  
  // Loop through each multiple-choice item and remove it
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    
    form.deleteItem(items[i]); // Remove the item from the form
  }
  console.log("Sleeping for "+sleepDurations/1000+" second(s)")
  Utilities.sleep(sleepDurations)
}

function createMultipleChoiceQuestion(countRandomQuestion=2) {
  clearMultipleChoiceQuestions() // to delete all items before creating a new one
  let form = FormApp.openById(destinationForms); // Get the active form
  let questionList = getQuestionsAndChoice()
  let selectedQuestions = pickRandomQuestionsWithOptions(questionList,countRandomQuestion)
  let item = ""
  console.log("Generating Question...")
  for(var title in selectedQuestions){
    let question_title = selectedQuestions[title]['question']
    let question_choices = selectedQuestions[title]['options']
    console.log("Adding question: "+question_title)
    console.log("Adding choices: "+question_choices)

    // Add a multiple-choice question
    item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
     item.setTitle(question_title)
    .setChoiceValues(question_choices); // Set the choices for the question
  }
}
```

When i execute them from backend (app script), all went good:

- Old Questions are deleted
- New Questions are recreated

I applied some triggers:

- form Submit
- timer trigger per minute
  They didn't work. They only deleted the questions without recreating new questions.

i'm confuse because we were executing the same scripts through different operations (app script backend manually click run script & trigger) bring different results.

How do i resolve this?

Update:
i add Trigger Executions
[image]

Comment: I was able to test `clearMultipleChoiceQuestions()`, and it's working as it should. However, I couldn't fully test `createMultipleChoiceQuestion()` since the function `getQuestionsAndChoice()` is missing from it. May I ask what your end goal is as to why you're using [`onFormSubmit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onformsubmit) and are trying to [`Manage triggers manually`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_manually) per minute?

Comment: I store questions in a Google Form. Then i'm using App Script to retrieve 2 random question and published into the new Google Form. I'm using `onFormSubmit()` because i think it would execute the script as form submitted and recreate another 2 random question. I want users respond 2 random question differently dynamically. @Saddles. Since onFormSubmit() isn't working, i tried manual trigger per minute also. Both of them are not working.

Comment: Gotcha. Since you mentioned that it's working properly when you manually run the script, can you share the `Executions` tab of your Google Apps Script for both the `onFormSubmit()` and the `time-driven trigger` to see if it generated any errors? Also, are you using [`Container-bound Scripts`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) or [`Standalone Scripts`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) in this matter?

Comment: hi @Saddles i just reinstalled the only one trigger: `onFormSubmit()`. i submitted my form and it triggers The Trigger. I checked its Executions it's complete without any error. 

I get back to the google form, no question showed up.

Currently, there are 2 way to make the script work:
1. Execute from Apps Script (Container-bound Scripts)
2. Create a button in html deployed web page, and call the function inside code.gs using a button in html

all triggers are not working

Comment: i tried to create a button in html web page and call `createMultipleChoiceQuestion` from that button, still doesn't work as expected even though all questions were deleted, another random questions wasn't recreated.

Comment: Since you can make the function work when you run it manually with triggers not working, I recommend that you submit a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) to let Google know about the unusual behavior that's going on.

Comment: Now, if you have time and would still like to try and work on this, you can try running the trigger from Google Sheets instead of Google Forms. Remove the trigger first in the `Script editor` of the form, then go to **`Responses`** > **`Link to Sheets`** or **`View in Sheets`**. Afterwards, go to **`Extensions`** > **`Apps Script`** to set it up.

Comment: By the way, I'm curious how `getQuestionsAndChoice()` and `pickRandomQuestionsWithOptions()` are set up. If my last recommendation doesn't work, can you update the question to include those functions? I found similar questions to what you're experiencing here on Stack Overflow, but everything is on a case-by-case basis.